# Optimization of quadratic fractions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Is there an efficient way (for example to convexify, lower bound (except special cases),  or something like that) to optimize quadratic fractions?

For example: 
$$
min_x \frac{x^\top A x + x^\top B  + C}{ x^\top D x + x^\top E + F  }
$$

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://www-optima.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/result/masterdoc/19zhang.pdf) paper. It gives a very high level description,but I think you will find what are you looking for there.

In short, this paper uses Newton method to obtain upper and lower bounds on the objective and later uses the solution of a CDT subproblem(defined therein) to obtain solutions.

Can you tell where have you encountered such objective functions? I am curious.

Comment: This is a working project, so I cannot details, but we are optimizing network of electric circuits.